# What is the correct way test the file upload through swagger-client?

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I need to write a valid test of a file upload through swagger client but I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong or possible solutions

```
const requestBody = {
      name: 'USUÁRIO TESTE',
      cpf: 'PROCESSO DE TESTE/DEPLOY KAER-MORHEN',
      email: 'POR FAVOR IGNORE ESTE E-MAIL',
      phone: 'OBRIGADO',
      id: 'cj2c3rtea00010epfu0sfdhf7',
      back: tmp.fileSync({ prefix: 'document-', postfix: '.jpg' }).name
    }

return client.apis.documents.sendDocumentsEmail(undefined, {
  requestBody
})
  .should.be.fulfilled()
  .then(({ status, body }) => {
    status.should.be.eql(200)
    body.should.be.Object()
  })
```

I'm also using Multer as middleware, and when I send the tmp file or creating a file with fs it doesn't get recognized and the attribute ends up beeing treated as a string.
What would be the simplest way to send a valid multipart/form-data with a valid file using swagger-client?

```
/documents/upload:
    x-middlewares:
      - "multer"
    post:
      tags:
        - "documents"
        - "kaermorhen"
      summary: "Upload documents"
      x-swagger-router-controller: "document.controller"
      operationId: "sendDocumentsEmail"  
      requestBody:
        description: "Documents upload"
        required: true
        x-name: "body"
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: "object"
              required:
                - "id"
              properties:
                id:
                  type: "string"
                name:
                  type: "string"
                cpf:
                  type: "string"
                email:
                  type: "string"
                phone:
                  type: "string"
                front:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                back:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                residence:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
```